# PHP exec call not playing ball, despite command working well in terminal

Tags: php, python, exec

Afternoon all.

Here's a line of PHP:

```
$command = 'python /path/to/file/script.py '.escapeshellarg($arg1).' '.escapeshellarg($arg2).' '.escapeshellarg($arg3).' > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &';
```

When I `echo` that command, and copy and paste it into terminal my code runs absolutely perfectly (takes about 3 minutes to send me the status email which is part of 'script.py'. It is not, however, running when started through PHP as part of a larger project.

Any obvious points I've missed here? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It's possible that `exec()` is disabled on your server.  You can test this with: `if(function_exists('exec')) {
    echo "exec is enabled";
}`

Comment: What's PHP showing ? Is it showing any error ?

Comment: @MichaelDoye – adding that code output that exec is indeed enabled, thanks for the tip though.

Comment: @phpfresher No error from PHP about this particular line, no.